# Dynamically adding layouts efficiently

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have JSON that I'm parsing and based on the JSON, I will have different layouts that could include edit texts, date/time picker, etc. By pressing the next or back arrow, the user will essentially be moving to the next JSON object, which will show the corresponding layout. My question is, what would be the most efficient way to show these different layouts. I currently am thinking about creating an activity and having fragments for each layout. Though, using this method, I would have like 10+ fragments, which I feel is not efficient. Another scenario I thought of, would be to call setContentView() each time back or next is pressed. However, I need to be able to get the text from those edit text fields and save it. So, I don't think that setContentView() would really work. My best solution so far is a bunch of fragments, and on the onPause() for those fragments, I would save the data entered.

Comment: For your second approach you could set id for Edittext dynamically or just save instance of edittext and get data on next/back action.

Comment: The problem with this I think is that, I would need a giant switch statement just to see if there is an edittext in the activity, or a date/time picker, etc

Comment: Your question is too general. You could use both or your approach. In case your set of data could be changed in future 2nd variant will be better otherwise just create all variants for your layouts and be happy;)